# smooth transitions between external swfs.

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to get back into flash. trying to write some code here but...well, let me show you.

what I want and currently have is a main swf that loads in assets based on buttons pressed. I have 3 external SWFs (for the sake of this example, lets call the initial loaded swf "indexExt.swf", file two" f02.swf" and file three, " f03.swf") and in each of them,there's one layer that goes from frame 1 to frame 10.

On frame 1, there's an "intro" label, on frame 5, an "outro" label, and on frame 10, an " end" label.

indexExt.swf is loaded on initial load of the main swf.

as for my buttons, I gave my buttons on the main swf stage, instance names that are the same name as the external swfs so that with this line `event.target.name + ".swf"` I can call em in without having to re-write code for every button etc..

the button code im using for normal importing is this below:

```
f01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,btnclick);
f02.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,btnclick);


function btnclick(event:MouseEvent):void{

removeChild(loader);

var newSwfRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest( event.target.name + ".swf");

loader.load(newSwfRequest);
loader.x = Xpos;
loader.y = Ypos;
addChild(loader);

}
```

now the problem I'm having is that I don't know how to target whatever is clicked / imported /loaded in.

Overall, what I want to do is, rework the button code above, into something like so below:

```
// non code but you get the idea //


on press, if something is loaded, go to and play its "outro" frame label.
if "end frame label" load in event.target.name + ".swf"
```

i hope its not confusing. essentially what i want is that on button press, that whatever movie is loaded, play the outro label and IF and when, the "end" label is hit, load up whatever the user clicked on.

I think this is a sound way of doing it but, I tend to sometimes go for the hardest method. I'm no where near a pro but any hints /tips/code etc, I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a listener to your loader object for a complete event. That will give you the reference you're looking for. Then you can tell that object, if set, to go to the desired frame when your button is clicked.

```
var loaded:Object;

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoaded);

function handleLoaded(e:Event):void {
  loaded = e.target.content;
}

btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);

function handleClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
  if (loaded) {
    loaded.gotoAndPlay("outro");
  }

  //load new swf
}
```

Comment: Hi Hotn. thanks for the reply. i have a question. i understand what you mean to explain, but on your second line, what is " loaderContentInfo" ?

Comment: contentLoaderInfo is a property that exists on Loader objects that will allow you access to information about what's being loaded, such as bytes loaded and bytes total, as well as a reference to the actual content that's loaded. It's also the object that dispatches the events for the loader's progress, which is why the listener needs to be added there instead of directly to the Loader object.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#contentLoaderInfo

Comment: LOL ok. i see. i ask cause i see it but, in flash, the "loaderContentInfo" didnt turn blue for code...so i thought it was a variable or somethig you forgot to mention or something. but i now see, it was a typo, you put loaderContentInfo, and its contentLoaderInfo lol. no biggie, thanks for the help. ill try to work it now

Comment: HotN, thanks for the help so far. only problem im having now is. that, no matter how i put this to fit my needs, i get an error that reads: Line 65 1120: Access of undefined property event. And thats from this line:  " loaded = event.target.content; " . I do understand the over all concept of which youve tried to teach me but that one line is getting me down lol. any ideas? Again, thanks

Comment: Whoops, sorry about the misnaming of contentLoaderInfo. Fixed that in my post. As for your error, it's happening because the object reference you're using to get to target.content needs to match the parameters coming into your function. In my example above, note that the parameter is "e:Event". e is the name of the var, Event is the type. so you must use "loaded = e.target.content".  The variable "event" never exists, causing your error.

Comment: AHHH OK!!!! i see lol. but ...i gues while rewriting it i used " event " . but isnt "e" and "evt" and "event" all the same thing? thanks again

Comment: Variable instance names can be whatever you want but they have to match. If you used "evt:Event" as your param, you need to use "loaded = evt.target.event". You could just as easily use "foo:Event" as long as you use "loaded = foo.target.event" to match. It's just an arbitrary name to indicate which object instance you're referring to.